# Adding a variable into a string

Tags: python

I added this line of Code:

```
tweet_string = 'Starting activity for insta'
os.system("python3 tweet.py tweet_string")
```

As you can see the tweet script uses the first argument as tweet context. Unfortunately I don't know how to use the variable correct... Can you assist me here?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre need a space after `python3 tweet.py`.

Comment: @birryree it probably doesn't work like this, the string needs quoting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, don't pass your variable name in the literal string...

Just adding out of quotes doesn't cut it because of the spaces. You have to protect with quotes.

it should be:

```
os.system('python3 tweet.py "{}"'.format(tweet_string))
```

(better, but if there's a quote in `tweet_string` you'll have an issue again)

Anyway: don't use `os.system` it's deprecated. This is better and handles quoting automatically:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["python3","tweet.py",tweet_string])
```

(Python 3.5 added a unified [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) method which can check return code or not, redirect output in a variable or not, which is the recommended approach to run a subprocess if you don't need to be compatible with previous versions)

Of course, always ask yourself the question when running a python subprocess inside a python module: wouldn't it be easier to import the module and call a function?

Answer (score 1):

In general

```
('python3 tweet.py "' + tweet_string + '"')
```

If you're using python 3.6

```
f('python3 tweet.py "{tweet_string}"')
```

Comment: and os.system is deprecated. I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: Try to tweet anything with a quote in it…